# AS3 Array Buttons Nested

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a list of buttons:

agreeButton
disagreeButton
container.clickButton1
container.clickButton2

Container is another movieclip and inside of it are the last 2 buttons.

How can I put it in array and have all the same listeners applied to each of them?

```
var buttonArray:Array = new Array("agreeButton", "disagreeButton", "container.clickButton1", "container.clickButton2");
for (var i:int=0; i<buttonArray.length; i++) {
    this[buttonArray[i]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseRollOver);
    this[buttonArray[i]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseRollOut);
    this[buttonArray[i]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the buttons and add them to an array.

```
var agreeButton:Button = new Button();
var disagreeButton:Button = new Button();

//... Code that will add the above instantiated buttons to the canvas

var buttonArray:Array = new Array(agreeButton, disagreeButton);

for (var i:int = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {    
buttonArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
}


private function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    Alert.show("Boom!");
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, what about the "container.clickButton1", "container.clickButton2" buttons? They are in a movieclip named "container". How do you declare the variable in a movieclip?

Comment: Also I used SimpleButton instead.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the buttons are as long as you have a reference to them from the code. Declare the buttons, add the event listeners and then add them to the container. Got it? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `button` class that is extended by each of these buttons. In the button class you add `eventListeners`.

Example:

forgive me if there are things wrong with this, I haven't coded in AS3 for a while.

```
class MyButton extends Button
{
    public function MyButton()
    {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseRollOver);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseRollOut);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
    }
    //... Add mouseRollOver, mouseRollOut, mouseClick methods
}
```

Your Individual Buttons

```
class DisagreeButton extends MyButton
{
    public function DisagreeButton()
    {

    } 
}

class AgreeButton extends MyButton
{
    public function AgreeButton()
    {

    } 
}
```

Once you instantiate the buttons all the event listeners will be applied to each.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: @Anderson I added a rough example of what I was referring to